# How to rotate text in pdfpages put command

Tags: rotating, pdfpages

I'm using the `pdfpages` package to annotate some text lables on to a PDF plot `fig.pdf`. I want to rotate the text 90 degrees but do not find anything in the documentation that says how to do this...  Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[14pt]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\huge
\bf
\includepdf[picturecommand={
\put(200,300){\colorbox{white}{(title)}}
}]{fig.pdf}
\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\rotatebox{90}{\colorbox{white}{(title)}}
```